# Swift MacOS dismiss nsviewcontroller presented by seque

Tags: swift, macos, segue, nsviewcontroller

I'm running into some confusion with a segue to a NSViewController and dismissing it.

In my StoryBoard I have a segue from ViewController to BlockViewController set as a sheet with an idenitfier of `showBlockVC`

Here's the segue code which is triggered from a button click:

```
@IBAction func addBlock(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showBlockVC", sender: sender)
}
```

In BlockViewController I have a cancel button and clicking it simply dismisses the VC:

```
@IBAction func cancelBlock(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(self)
}
```

This works to some extent, the BVC animates away and ViewControlleer is presented on screen. (Though I am not sure if it was ever removed or just left under BVC)

My issue is I need VC (the root) to know BVC has been dismissed. But Apple, I don't know when, it's been a while since I've done desktop work removed the completion handler from `dismiss()`. Even if I wanted to call a function back on VC, when I print `parent` to the log in BVC's `viewDidLoad` I get `nil`. Why doesn't BVC see VC as it's parent?

In VC, if I print to the log from `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` they only print on the inital load of VC.

I'm sure I've wired something wrong but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Forgot to add, I am working around this by using notifications, in viewWillDisappear on BVC I send a notification and have an observer set up in VC, but this seems kind of hacky...

Answer (score 0):

So in your code you're calling self.dismiss(self) The reason this code works is because the message of dismiss gets forwarded up the responder chain.
self.presentingViewController is your "ViewController."
If you look at the documentation a view controller cannot present or dismiss itself. If you want to communicate with the view controller presenting you you can simply use the presentingViewController property and cast it to be type ViewController to get backwards communications. You don't have to communicate that you are being dismissed though. The presenting view controller is the one actually dismissing you.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434439-presentingviewcontroller

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

Comment: The question is about `NSViewController` and `NSViewController` can [dismiss](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434447-dismiss) itself.

Comment: Are you sure? Because if I call dismiss on my root view controller it doesn't seem to work. In other words my top level vc of the window. In fact I get this message in debugger -> dismissViewController:: Error: maybe this view controller was not presented?

Comment: How do you call `dismiss`, which class is the argument? In Objective-C the methods are called `dismissViewController:` and `dismissController:`, in Swift they are both called `dismiss`. The compiler calls `dismissViewController:` if the argument is a `NSViewController`.

Comment: If I make a new macOS app with story board and swift. add 1 push button to the view controller in story board with action outlet calling in code self.dismiss(self) it raises an exception with the error above.

Comment: @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(self)
    }

Comment: Note that adding a second vc in between to present the one with the button works fine.

Comment: `self.dismiss(self)` calls `dismissViewController:` because `self` is a `NSViewController`. It's either `self.presentingViewController.dismiss(self)` (= `dismissViewController:`) or `self.dismiss(sender)` (= `dismissController:`). Or connect the button in the storyboard to its view controller and `dismissController:`.